# How to sort alphanumeric values in SQL Server properly

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column with an alphanumeric value called **TableName** which could be almost any phrase as long as it is alphanumeric.

Sample data could be (Not necessarily 3 alphabet followed by a number)

```
AAA 1
AAB 2
AAC 3
AAB 10
AAC 12
AAB 12
```

If i use a normal sort like **ORDER BY TableName**

This will become

```
AAA 1
AAB 10
AAB 12
AAB 2
AAC 12
AAC 3
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is

```
AAA 1
AAB 2
AAB 10
AAB 12
AAC 3
AAC 12
```

I'd like you to know that this field COULD be ANYTHING 
i.e.

```
ABC123MAS3482
KASJ19LKA
213LKS23
```

Just to let you know that there is no format in the field. 
The only rule is that it is alpha numeric.

I hope you guys could help me with your advance knowledge in SQL.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this cannot be done too easily.

Your statement `I'd like you to know that this field COULD be ANYTHING i.e.` pretty much kills it, otherwise one could have split alphabetic and numeric values in two columns or let them be split by some string-function.

But this way the only way out I could see is:

*Write your own function that returns a numeric value by which you can sort.
Then you can use it like this:*

`SELECT AlphaNumericValue FROM ValuesTable ORDER BY dbo.GETSORTVALUE(AlphaNumericValue)`

This could be a dummy body for such a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GETSORTVALUE(@value NVARCHAR)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dummyValue INT = LEN(@value)
    -- do something with your string here to get a sorting number
    RETURN @dummyValue
END
```

Since the values inside your column could be `anything` you would need to come up with a good sorting first, that should be included in that function then.
For example you did not yet define how to sort in this case:

You say `AAB 2` should come before `AAB 10`, but what about `AA2B` and `AA10B`?

Once you've defined this, your custom logic should go into that function.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting alphanumeric column in a different way:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn varchar(50) NULL)

INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('3')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('AB1')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('A1')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('B2')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('A11')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('B20')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('B21')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('AB10')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('B3')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('AB100')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('B32')
INSERT INTO dbo.AlphnumericTable (AlphnumericColumn) VALUES ('11')
SELECT AlphnumericColumn FROM dbo.AlphnumericTable
--Show normal Sort
SELECT AlphnumericColumn FROM dbo.AlphnumericTable ORDER BY AlphnumericColumn
--Show AlphaNumberic Sort
SELECT AlphnumericColumn FROM dbo.AlphnumericTable ORDER BY LEFT(AlphnumericColumn,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',AlphnumericColumn)-1), -- alphabetical sort
CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(AlphnumericColumn,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',AlphnumericColumn),LEN(AlphnumericColumn))) -- numerical sort
--cleanup our work
DROP Table dbo.AlphnumericTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a function to insert a leading zero in front of each substring of numbers and sort by that. You might want to store that in a column and update whenever the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

Create this function

```
create function dbo.udf_ExpandDigits(@src varchar(1024), @plen int, @letter 
char(1))
returns varchar(max)
 as 
begin
if @plen >= 100
  return @src;
declare @p int, @p2 int, @num varchar(100);
declare @ret_val varchar(max)='';
if (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @src) =0 )
  set @ret_val = @src;
else
begin
  set @p = patindex('%[0-9]%', @src);


  while(@p > 0)
  begin
     set @p2=patindex('%[^0-9]%', substring(@src, @p, 1000)) 
     if (@p2 > 0)
     begin
        set @num=substring(@src, @p, @p2-1);
        set @ret_val += left(@src, @p-1) + case when len(@num) < @plen then right(replicate(@letter, @plen) + @num, @plen) else @num end; ;
        set @src = substring(@src, @p+@p2-1, len(@src));
        set @p = patindex('%[0-9]%', @src);
     end
     else
     begin
        set @num = substring(@src, @p, len(@src));
        set @ret_val += left(@src, @p-1)+ case when len(@num) < @plen then right(replicate(@letter, @plen) + @num, @plen) else @num end;
        set @src ='';
        break;
     end

  end -- while (@p > 0)
  if len(@src) > 0
     set @ret_val += @src;
 end -- else
 return @ret_val;
end -- function
```

and use it like example:

```
SELECT 
  your_column ,
  Formatted_Code=dbo.udf_ExpandDigits(your_column, 3, '0')
        
 FROM 
    your_table
order by
    Formatted_Code
```